# Let's Encrypt's root cert is not self signed

Tags: validation, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

We sell a product that sets up several web services, each serving on a bunch of endpoints, some of them even supporting arbitrary sub-FQDNs. With this I mean that if the endpoint is `foo.example.com`, then it also serves `*.foo.example.com`.

Anyways, one of the features we want to provide is the ability of accepting any bunch of certificates and private keys, sort them by endpoint, validate them and push them to the different services. This means that we can accept anything between a single file with a cert covering all the endpoints ans SANs and its private key and the whole chain up to the CA root; and a bunch of files containing anything and figure out whether they're certs, what kind, where they do apply, etc. We decided to do this because certs are hard enough already, so we want to remove the onus of doing all this from the client.

The way we're doing this is as follows: For each endpoint, we find a cert that covers it. Then we find the key that matches and the chain back to the top.

My issue is with the last part of that last part. We consider we found the top of the chain when we find a self signed certificate with the CA bit on. Imagine my surprise when yesterday a colleague handed me a root cert with this:

```
Issuer: O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
Subject: C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
```

That's Let's Encrypt root cert not being self signed but signed by someone else. Is this OK?

The only hint to a solution comes later when I find in the cert:

```
Authority Information Access: 
CA Issuers - URI:http://apps.identrust.com/roots/dstrootcax3.p7c
```

Should I (automatically) download that file to complete the chain building? Or should I search for the `C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1` cert in the system's trusted roots? Notice that because our product can be installed in dark sites, the former is not really an option.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is rather complex, I'll try to make a bullet list:

- When validating a chain, always use a trust store first. For instance, recent Linuxes have one somewhere in `/etc/ssl`. This means that if you like me are backtracking from the final cert, you should look for Issuers first in the trust store, then in the (untrusted) provided chain, otherwise you end up with [the same bug `openssl-1.0.2` has](https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2021/09/13/LetsEncryptRootCertExpire/).
- Once validated this way, *provide the original chain for maximum compatibility*. This is because the original LE chain's 'root' cert is either replaced with the new (since 2015!) LE self-signed root with the previous algorithm, or it is validated with the missing 'real' root that has expired last year. This seems to be the case with very old Android systems (hence the reason LE provides this chain by default in the first place).
- You can always ask LE for a newer chain with the SS root cert, but as stated above, this is less compatible. If you can live without pre-2015 clients, it's probably the best way.